# is it allowed to compare two pointers of type `char *`

Tags: c, pointers

Is it allowed to compare two pointers of type `char *`
like the  `p<pkt+n` in the snippet? If not allowed, is there any better way to replace this while condition?

```
      int n = 40;
      char *pkt = malloc(4);
       ...
      char *p;
      p=pkt;

      while(p<pkt+n){
           ...
           p+=4;
           ...
           p++;
           ..blabla
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's allowed.  Do note that you're only allocating 4 bytes, but you will continue iterating the loop for 40 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

It is allowed if both pointers point into the same "object", such as a single memory allocation, same struct, or same array.

The compiler will generally allow you to compare pointers to different objects, but the results aren't guaranteed to have any specific meaning.  For example,

```
char *x = malloc(10);
char *y = malloc(10);
if (y > x) { ... }
```

The compiler (probably) won't complain about the comparison in the if-statement, but it's not guaranteed to have any particular meaning.  On most platforms, however, this will actually compare the addresses as you'd expect.

Comment: `==` and `!=` comparison are allowed for any valid pointers, including null pointers. `<` et al are allowed only if both pointers point to elements of the same array or just past the end of it; for this purpose, a single object is treated as a 1-element array.

Comment: My answer was a little rushed, so I focused on the context in the question.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

The original condition is valid as long as the pointers involved in comparison are pointing at elements of the same array or one step past its end. You can also replace it with equivalent condition

```
while (p - pkt < n)
```

The latter variant compares integers instead of pointers, but still relies on the very same pointer properties as your original variant does. In other words, it is just a matter of personal taste.